# How to properly set dependencies with C++Builder between cpp files & headers

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have a project with many libs, one BPL, and one executable.

Now, in the IDE, I've setup some dependencies, but C++Builder seems to take a simple approach to dependencies:

It only allows «binary dependencies», not «source file dependencies».

For example:

`A.cpp` & `A.h` -> `A.exe`, which depends on `B.a`, which has `B.cpp` & `B.h`

If I change `B.h`, I Make (Make in IDE) `A.exe`, it rebuilds `B.a` but does not recompile `A.cpp`, so the program «violated» the ODR of C++.

Is this a limitation of the C++Builder IDE?

A colleague just told me to Build (Build in IDE) every time, he's been working with Embarcadero for 10 years and tells me it's the only way!

My project takes about one hour to build, instead I'd like to do incremental builds to speed up development.

I'm using C++Builder 10.4, if that matters!

Answer (score 0):

`B.a` is a static lib, not a header file. So it is not used by the *compiler* at all, only by the *linker*.

"Make" rebuilds the object/executable files for `A.exe` only if its own source files are changed, ie `A.cpp` or `A.h`, or if any of `A.exe`'s *dependencies in the same [**project group**](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_a_Project_to_the_Project_Group)* are changed.

Are your projects for `A.exe` and `B.a` stored in a **project group**, or are you compiling them independently?

If they are in the same project group, then you can specify `B.a` as a [dependency](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Project_Dependencies) for `A.exe`, so that "Make"'ing `A.exe` will first "Make" `B.a`, thus rebuilding the object/executable files for `B.a` if needed.  At that point, if the IDE still doesn't recompile the object/executable files for `A.exe` when the object/executable files for `B.a` change, then you need to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Otherwise, since `A.cpp` does not *directly* depend on `B.a`, there is no reason for "Make" to rebuild the object/executable files for `A.exe` when `B.h` changes, unless `A.cpp` (in)directly `#include`'s `B.h` itself.

Comment: sorry I was not clear, A.c does include B.h, so when B.h changes, even if it is a comment, we want A.c to be recompile. If not we risk ODR violation.
A.c, has is own cbproj, so does B.c. They are both (cbProj)  «inside» a groupproj
Now C++Builder does not seem to knows that A.c needs B.h to be built 
if I include B.h inside A.c via #include, how can I make sure the C++Builder will know that every time I change B.h, A.c must be recompiled ?
maybe there is something in the IDE I must enable, or something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, for me the .a & the .bpl are almost the same. my real life project contains both. I notice that when a header change, C++builder does not seems to recompile the dependent .cpp file if they are in another cbproj.
from my executable I call functions/methods in .a or in BPL, and I expect the structure/classes to be the same layout. I rely on incremental build

Comment: "*A.c does include B.h, so when B.h changes, even if it is a comment, we want A.c to be recompile*" - then yes, Make should be recompiling A.c. "*how can I make sure the C++Builder will know that every time I change B.h, A.c must be recompiled?*" - it should already be picking it up when you Make the A.exe project. If it is not, then [report the problem](https://quality.embarcadero.com) to Embarcadero. "*maybe there is something in the IDE I must enable, or something I'm doing wrong*" - there is not. "*I rely on incremental build*" - I've never had luck with IB, I always do full builds.

Comment: Thx for the answer. you seems to say that the IDE will recompile A.c when B.h change.
I will do more tests, and report problems if I found that not to be the case!

You say: you never had luck with incremental build.

This confuse me: in the project menu I have two options: 
- Compile All : this is the one I call incremental build as it seems to compile only what has changed 
- Build All: which compile everything, even when files haven't changed since the last build

Am I wrong for calling Compile All: «incremental build» ?